# Photon pair generation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, experimental-physics

Where one can buy a crystal for photon pair generation? Can it work with a LED to be registered with a CCD or LED is low and a laser is needed?
Thanks very much for who can help. I found a company producing BBO but they had no experience with Photon pair.

Comment: What you mean exactly by "photon pair",- Does these photons must be entangled together or not ? What properties of photons must be,- Does they need to be of same energy or polarization ? In what they should be generated ? If you need just split beam of light into pair of beams,- use birefringence in some crystals,- these you can [buy easily](https://www.newlightphotonics.com/Birefringent-Crystals/Calcite-Crystals), because they are used in making polarization plates.

Comment: https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=15827

Comment: https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=15444

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be referring to [spontaneous parametric downconversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_parametric_down-conversion). It is not an easy experiment to do. You need a strong laser in the UV to get down-conversed photons at the red end of the visible spectrum. If the down-conversion is done with a strong enough pump laser, you should be able to observe the down-converted light with a CCD camera. If you want to do more sophisticated experiments like testing Bell's inequality, you'll need sensitive detectors that can register single photons together with a coincidence counter.

Answer (score 0):

Edmund optics. Thor labs. They are the big and also expensive suppliers for all the university and company labs.

What type of experiment are you doing?

Eraser?

I think you need a laser for bbo and it has to have a certain  wavelength … in the visible to make pairs. Output is ir so you can not see it.  I think rasp pi camera can just see it … for cheap camera maybe Sony starvis2 sensor is best for ir.

Comment: These companies are expensive. I found EKSMA selling bbo for 320£. But the stuff doesn't know can they do the job. No data. My intention is to use a  cheap light emiting diode 375 nm to a BBO to get 750 nm entangled pair at 6 grade apart and to register the Flux with ccd as a teaching purpose. CCD can be set to work for hours accumulating the photons. Also I can use a plate to reinforce the photons before ccd?

Comment: I think Thor had crystal for 500 us$. And Thor also has tutorial how to use it.

Comment: Maybe you can find used lab equipment website on Google.

Comment: Plate?  You mean filter?  I think many of the led photons will come thru the bbo to the ccd.

Comment: If course filter for the laser 375 nm is necessary but if light 750 is weak there are scintillation plates doing like avalanche before CCD. I read about recently I don't know exact name.

Comment: Scintillation plates are used for x-ray photons so I think it does not make sense.  You should go on the Thor labs website for BBO because they are a very good website and tell you how to set things up for observation.